# R - Count the number of words in a text string variable

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, while-loop

I want to count the number of words in a text  my data.

Then

I want to use a loop to count the number of words in a specific column "Opinion" for every row in my data.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

We can use `str_count` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
df1$nwords <- str_count(df1$Opinion, "\\w+")
```

---

Or using a `for` loop

```
df1$nwords <- NA_integer_
for(i in seq_along(df1$Opinion)) {
      df1$nwords[i] <- length(strsplit(df1$Opinion[i], "\\s+")[[1]])
 }
```

Or with `strsplit` on the whole column

```
df1$nwords <- lengths(strsplit(df1$Opinion, "\\s+"))
```

Comment: @JoeBens `df1$nwords <- `